# Dismiss Keyboard with inputAccessoryView

Tags: objective-c, swift

The textview is docked at the bottom (like the messages app). However, the keyboard wont dismiss when the user taps outside the textView.

```
import UIKit
class CommentsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var commentBar: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var commentTextField: UITextField!

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
        return commentBar
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        commentBar.removeFromSuperview()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
        return false;
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true);
        commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

Comment: Check if your view enabled user interaction.

Comment: @BrittoThomas yes user interaction is enabled

Answer (score 1):

No need to remove your commentBar at canBecomeFirstResponder Method. This will call each time keyboard resign.

Try some thing like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var commentBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet var commentTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       commentBar.removeFromSuperview()
    }
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
       return commentBar
    }

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
       return true
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
       self.view.endEditing(true);
       return false;
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
      self.view.endEditing(true);
      commentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, i gave this a try, but its still not dismissing the keyboard. Also, if I present another view controller (like login) and go back, the `commentBar` disappears completely.

Comment: check whether func touchesBegan is calling, use break points.

Comment: Also check the connection of textField to IBOutlet.

Comment: Yes, the textField is connected `@IBOutlet var commentTextField: UITextField!` And I used a breakpoint and found that the `touchesBegan` never was called.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   self.view.endEditing(true)
   return true
}
```

Comment: You should give some explanation of your answer